# How Intellij idea reduce memory after project was closed?

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt

I have opened several projects in Intellij Idea. A [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) tool  indicates that idea64.exe    process uses ~2Gb as private Bytes and 3,5Gb as virtual size. When I closed several big sbt projects, but memory usage stayed the same. Is it a bug? Can I manually run somethink like "refresh" to free memory usage from closed projects?

Answer (score 3):

Intellij IDEA is a Java application and therefore its memory is managed by JVM. Short answer is no, you cannot force JVM to free memory when you tell it to. Depending what do you want to achieve, you can change memory limits for IDEA as described here (you want to decrease it probably): https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: actually, you can ask IntelliJ to free up the memory by clicking on the memory usage indicator in the right bottom corner of main window.

Comment: So if Intellij allocated several GB they should live in heap forever? I do not think so. There is should be a mechanizm for reducing memroy usage.

Comment: If IntelliJ still needs that memory then you have no choice. If it doesn't need it, it will be freed by the garbage collector.